# Including versions of maven projects into a war file for multimodule project

Tags: maven-2, war, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project witch is distributed as a zip archive with several war's inside. One of the war files servers as an "entry point" to the whole system. The system is built as a maven project. Each of wars in turn has its own pom.xml file witch defines packaging process.

My current task is to get versions of each war file and to include them into "main" war.

Currently i have configured all projects to produce file "project.version.properties". All those files are gathered with maven assembly plugin into the resulting zip archive:

```
zip
|___ main.war
|___ sub1.war
|___ sub2.war
|___ version (folder)
      |___ project1.version.properties
      |___ project2.version.properties
      |___ projectN.version.properties
```

Is it possible to create something like this? (I.e. to inject versions folder into the excising war)

```
zip
|___ main.war
      |___ version (folder)
            |___ project1.version.properties
            |___ project2.version.properties
            |___ projectN.version.properties
|___ sub1.war
|___ sub2.war
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty simple. See the example "[Adding web resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)" in the documentation.

**[EDIT]** To get the same effect with the Assembly plugin, add the file sets to the [Assembly Descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html) outside of the `moduleSets`. That allows to include arbitrary content in the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it possible to accomplish the task with the assembly plugin? I have a `moduleSets` in the assembly descriptor. Is it possible to use something like `<fileSet>
            <directory>versions</directory>
            <outputDirectory>my_war_file.war</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>`?